# Perl to set a directory to open, open it, then print the directory opened?

Tags: perl, operating-system, filepath

Trying to troubleshoot a port of some perl code from CentOS to Windows.

Really know nothing about Perl, and the code I'm porting is around 700-1000 lines. 100% sure one of the issues I'm seeing is related to how the code is being rendered as a result of being on the OS it's running on.

So, I'm looking for a way to troubleshoot debugging how the OS's are rendering filepath apart from the legacy code; which I can not post to SO due to "IP" reasons.

So, I looking for some perl that I can set a directory to open within the script (for example, C:\data\ or /home/data), then script attempts to load the directory, prints if it failed or succeeded, and then prints the string it attempted to load, regardless if the code failed to open the directory or not.

Open to suggestions, but that's the issue, and the solution I'm seeing.

Questions, feedback, requests - just comment, thanks!!

Comment: English might not be your first language, so apologies up-front...  Any chance you could re-read and/or edit what you have written (maybe use some punctuation too), as I am having a hard time grasping what is being asked, other than simply saying "print $filename.$/;"

Comment: @Mathew: Made a few edits, though main issue is I just don't know perl, and as a result what to ask for; for example, no idea what the perl you posted within your comment does.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
use IO::Dir;

my $dir = IO::Dir->new($dir_path) or 
   die "Could not open directory $dir_path: $!\n";
```

of course, where $dir_path is some path to a directory on your system that you want, either as a var or hard coded.  The more 'old school' way would look like:

```
opendir my $dir, $dir_path or die "Could not open directory $dir_path: $!\n";
```

That won't print of the directory is opened, but the program will fail if it doesn't open it then print the precise error as to why, which is what the $! variable holds.

Answer (score 1):

Is this what you're looking for?

```
use DirHandle;

my $dir = "test";
my $dh = new DirHandle($dir);

if($dh) {
  print "open directory succeeded\n";
}
else {
  print "open directory failed\n";
}

print $dir, "\n";
```

`new DirHandle` opens the directory and returns a handle to it.  The handle will be undef if the open failed.

Comment: Refer: [`DirHandle`](http://perldoc.perl.org/DirHandle.html) and [`opendir`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/opendir.html).

Comment: Indirect object notation is pretty much always a bad idea. Please use "DirHandle->new(...)" instead of "new DirHandle(...)" - particularly in example code.

Comment: Ok, agreed, I have a bad habit of using that notation.  Thanks for the correction.